# Sub string in free marker not working

Tags: java, solr, freemarker

I am trying to write a function which gets me the sub-string of a string stored in a variable.

I have done the following

```
  <#global summary_s = getSummarySubstring(activeItem, "44","")>


  <#function getSummarySubstring item summaryId>

        <#assign Summary = helper.getLinkedItems(item,summaryId,"")>

        <#assign SubSummary = ${Summary?substring(0,140)}>

        <#return SubSummary >

  </#function>
```

I get a freemarker error saying:

```
 Caused by: freemarker.core.ParseException: Encountered "{" at line 111, column 36 in 
  remoteIndexing_555_16.                                              
  Was expecting one of:
  "in" ...
   ">" ...
   <EMPTY_DIRECTIVE_END> ...
   "." ...
  "[" ...
  "(" ...
   "?" ...
  "!" ...
   <TERMINATING_EXCLAM> ...
   "??" ...
   "+" ...
    "-" ...
   "*" ...
   "/" ...
   "%" ...
   "!=" ...
   "=" ...
   "==" ...
   ">=" ...
   <ESCAPED_GTE> ...
   ">" ...

  <STRING_LITERAL> ...
```

Can any body help please ?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `${...}`

ie: `<#assign SubSummary = Summary.substring(0,140)>`

`${...}` is for printing to the outputstream

Comment: Thanks for your reply....with your solution the error is gone,but still am not getting the sub-string(0-140).

Comment: Can you pls post the code where you use the variable summary_s's value? Because as I see right now, you are assigning a global variable, but not using it anywhere, how do you want to get it then? I don't know about debugging Freemarker on client side, only showing values with ${valueToShow}